# Time Complexity of Determinant of a Matrix using cofactor method

Tags: python, time-complexity

Trying to use the method found on a web to get the determinant of a Matrix.
But I am not sure about the time complexity of this method because of the recursion used in the program.
I realized that there is

1. one for loop to loop through the element of first row
2. Recursion function to process a smaller matrix.

Is that mean the worst time complexity of the program is O(N^2)?

```
# python program to find
# determinant of matrix.
 
# defining a function to get the
# minor matrix after excluding
# i-th row and j-th column.
 
 
def getcofactor(m, i, j):
    return [row[: j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[: i] + m[i+1:])]
 
# defining the function to
# calculate determinant value
# of given matrix a.
 
 
def determinantOfMatrix(mat):
 
    # if given matrix is of order
    # 2*2 then simply return det
    # value by cross multiplying
    # elements of matrix.
    if(len(mat) == 2):
        value = mat[0][0] * mat[1][1] - mat[1][0] * mat[0][1]
        return value
 
    # initialize Sum to zero
    Sum = 0
 
    # loop to traverse each column
    # of matrix a.
    for current_column in range(len(mat)):
 
        # calculating the sign corresponding
        # to co-factor of that sub matrix.
        sign = (-1) ** (current_column)
 
        # calling the function recursily to
        # get determinant value of
        # sub matrix obtained.
        sub_det = determinantOfMatrix(getcofactor(mat, 0, current_column))
 
        # adding the calculated determinant
        # value of particular column
        # matrix to total Sum.
        Sum += (sign * mat[0][current_column] * sub_det)
 
    # returning the final Sum
    return Sum
 
 
# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # declaring the matrix.
    mat = [[1, 0, 2, -1],
           [3, 0, 0, 5],
           [2, 1, 4, -3],
           [1, 0, 5, 0]]
 
    # printing determinant value
    # by function call
    print('Determinant of the matrix is :', determinantOfMatrix(mat))
 
# This code is contributed by Amit Mangal.
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the determinant of an n x n matrix using cofactor methods requires evaluating the determinant of n matrices, each of size n-1, followed by about 2n operations (additions and multiplications).  Thus, the cost is T(n) = nT(n-1)+cn.  If you draw the recursion tree or use other methods to solve this recurrence, you would get T(n) = O(n!). This is much more than O(n^2).